# ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh'

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to use this example in my current project: https://github.com/rajithd/spring-boot-oauth2. I was able to get it to run step by step as directed, but when I try to bring this example into intellij as a Spring Boot project I run into the errors below. When I import the project I am using 1.4.4.RELEASE, because that is what I am using in my project.

I tried playing around with the pom and setting the dependency versions, but it did not work.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.rd.config.SecurityConfiguration$GlobalSecurityConfiguration
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:249) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at com.rd.SpringBootOauth2Application.main(SpringBootOauth2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class com.rd.config.SecurityConfiguration$GlobalSecurityConfiguration
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.filterConstructors(Enhancer.java:666) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:567) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanFactoryAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:252) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:138) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 12 common frames omitted


java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@a8ef162: startup date [Mon Mar 20 21:03:56 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:819) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at com.rd.SpringBootOauth2Application.main(SpringBootOauth2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@a8ef162: startup date [Mon Mar 20 21:03:56 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:819) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at com.rd.SpringBootOauth2Application.main(SpringBootOauth2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.rd</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-oauth2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-boot-oauth2</name>
<description>Spring boot oauth2</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!--<spring-security-oauth2.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>-->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <!--<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <!--<version>2.8.6</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <!--<version>2.2.2</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <!--<version>2.4.0</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <!--<version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <!--<version>5.2.4.Final</version>-->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to run by removing createExpressionHandler from SecurityConfiguration.class